# Do something while in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of files in one folder. What I want to do is add a column with the name of the file. I found a solution to this, but I want to optimize. Currently I am just adding the values from J2 to J1000 to make sure I cover all rows. This is not ideal as the amount of rows in each file differ. What I want to do is find a way to add the value matching the amount of rows that exists in the sheet.

I want to find a way to check if there is data in column A for each row and then add the value as long as there is some data in column A for each row.

My thoughts would be to do a while statement to check if each row in column A is different from an empty string and add the value as long as it is different from an empty string. However I am not sure how to implement this.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub AllWorkbooks()
   Dim MyFolder As String 'Path collected from the folder picker dialog
   Dim MyFile As String 'Filename obtained by DIR function
   Dim wbk As Workbook 'Used to loop through each workbook

   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'Opens the folder picker dialog to allow user selection
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .Title = "Please select a folder"
       .Show
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
           MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
           Exit Sub
       End If
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder
    End With

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder
    'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        'Opens the file and assigns to the wbk variable for future use
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & MyFile)
        'Replace the line below with the statements you would want your macro to perform
        Sheets(1).Range("j1").Value = "Date"
        Sheets(1).Range("j2:j1000").Value = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 10, 10)
        wbk.Close savechanges:=True
        MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: if you have "a lot of files in one folder"  (not sure what in your case is "a lot", but if it is above 100 and with 1000 of rows), - VBA is probably not the best option to go forward, as it needs "physically" open each file to read the data.
The best optimisation would be choosing another tool, for example Power Query or Python/Pandas.
As per checking Column A, - just use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A2:A" & LastRow))`

Comment: It's not really clear what information you want to extract from each file in addition to the name?